# Adding functionality to QField

Tags: qfield, widget

I have a question regarding adding functionality to QField.

I'm currently doing a school project, where the customer involved would like to have a functionality to QField, where basically by **tapping a geometry**, a sort of form would pop out where one could add observations about a geometry. The observations would include things such as when, where and by whom the observation was made, also there should be a place where one could choose what they observed from a set list of choices.

Basically I could add to a point layer various observations and do many of this stuff, but since the customer would need the system to be as fast and easy as possible and would like the data to be entered by tapping a geometry and then tied to that geometry, this way of making things apparently isn't simple and fast enough for them.

I don't know if it would be possible to program something like this to QField, or if there already exists a way to do this. Can you provide any kind of hint as to what direction I should take or what I should research, etc.? I can't seem to find much information about the subject.

Comment: Hi, what you describe is basically what QField is built for :) just set up a polygon layer and create the needed form like @sbec described.
Cheers Marco

Comment: Thank you for your comment Marco! I have just started exploring the possibilities and I'm still figuring this stuff out, I will give this a try! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think I can answer your questions and point you in the right direction. I would start by looking at your layer ( in QGIS) properties and navigate to the attributes form. QGIS has many widgets to select from. Have a look here at the QGIS documentation for some insight https://qfield.org/docs/prepare/attributes-form.html. This youtube video is also helpful and short but no sound, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qpJ9Etlop-Y and this one helps as well, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lzFtc8HZvyk.
I have successfully set up 10 layers that require all sort of attributes to be filled in including drop down menus, dates, names, etc. Some of these layers are mandatory that must be filled in or the data does not get collected, others are not, and others like date_created & date_modified, created_by & modified by are collected automatically. Good luck and I hope you found this useful.
[image: qfield widgets]

[image: qgis widgets]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! :) I am still figuring this stuff out and even though I have browsed through this documentation I failed to understand that the forms/widgets could be used like this ^^' I will give this a try!